# Prediction using SVM Regression?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I want use Support Vector Machine (SVM) for prediction. And with I have written code as follows using matlab function `fitrsvm` and `predict`,

```
tb = table(x,y)                                                  
Mdl = fitrsvm(tb,'y','KernelFunction','gaussian')                                                                          
YFit = predict(Mdl,tb);                                
scatter(x,y);                                                   
hold on                                                
plot(x,YFit,'r.')
```

The output I am getting [image: here] .
 Here blude is testing values (`tb`) and red is prediction using SVM. As you can clearly see this prediction is wrong. Could anyone tell me any way to improve the prediction close to the measured values ?

Comment: By default, `fitrsvm` uses a linear kernel function, resulting in a linear regression model. You should [specify your kernel function](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrsvm.html#input_argument_d0e362069) to perform non-linear fitting. Note that regression fitting may be more appropriate in your case.

Comment: How can you add kernel function in this given format. I tried and given me error. Any Idea ?

Comment: Its Gaussian kernel I want to add

Comment: I did it but still prediction is not correct as  much plz have a look if you can have any idea to improve this ?

Comment: I just did . Plz have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use Kernel Function like RBF or gaussian and so on.
[image]

the default Kernel of the SVM is K(xi, xj) = `xi*xj` and it is a linear kernel.Of course you can only get a linear regression result.

Code like

```
x = 0:0.01:5 ;
y = sin(x)+rand(1, length(x)) ;
x = x' ;
y = y' ;
tb = table(x,y) ;
Mdl = fitrsvm(tb,'y','KernelFunction','gaussian');
YFit = predict(Mdl,tb);                                
scatter(x,y);                                                   
hold on                                                
plot(x,YFit,'r.')
```

=======================================================================
  As for the accuracy of the result, it dependst on many factors like the type of Kernel, the punish coefficient adjustment or something else, it usually needs for times to adjust the parameters. cross-validation could help you to find a good set of parameters

Comment: Thanks for this. I did the same and got output as shown in question. But still I feel not much close to testing values. Could you suggest me what extra I can do to improve my prediction ? I heard about  BoxConstraint    KernelScale, Epsilon can help to improve my prediction but no idea how to use this into this problem

Comment: i think the simplest method to improve the accuracy is to do cross-validation to find a best train-set which have a best testing accuracy.As for the scale or punish coefficient and something else, it also works but needing adjustment,It is a dirty job.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you tell me some example on how to use cross-validation to find a best train-set for this purposes ?

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath If you have enough training samples, you could randomly    divide them into K folds, one(maybe two or some amount you like but dont be too large) of them as a test set and the remain one as training set.Use the training set to train your model and use the test set to test your model record the accuracy and the parameters of your current model, do this untill all of the training set is full used, Then use the model parameters in best accuracy.It is usually time-consuming.

Comment: Any example in matlab function ? There are so many. confused with many function. can u site one example which can do this ?

Comment: I just do cross-validation manually, some randomly sample and feed the training set to model are enough, I dont know whether there is a function in MATLAB can do this automatically and universal to all regression or classify models.Actually, Realizing it is not quite difficult, maybe you should take a try first